# Tomcat application cannot see my $PATH variable

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat

There is this tomcat application thats been running on one of our servers (written by someone else in our lab who is gone). I know very little about tomcat and how it works, but I've narrowed the problem down to two solutions.

The error I'm getting on my webpage is:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hmmtop": error=2, No such file or directory

**Server Information**
Tomcat Version  JVM Version JVM Vendor  OS Name OS Version  OS Architecture
Apache Tomcat/6.0.26    1.6.0_65-b14-462-10M4609    Apple Inc.  Mac OS X    10.6.8  x86_64

Before an os x update this script worked fine. Now it cannot find the program called 'hmmtop'. This program, 'hmmtop' is located : /Users/saierlab/bin/hmmtop, and certainly does exist.

**Solution 1)** 
I tried changing the file named 'myfile.java' to use the absolute path, which now looks like this:

```
String command = "/Users/RAVEN/bin/hmmtop -if=" + this.fileName + ".fa";
```

This file was located in "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/avehas/WEB-INF/classes"
However, when I change it nothing is reflected. I'm not sure how to compile these changes. I tried running javarc myfile.java and it just gave me hundreds of errors, so I don't think thats how I go about this. Mind you I've never used Tomcat before.

I don't have the original WAR file or anything, and whats in that directory is all that I have pertaining to this particular program.

**Solution 2)**
If I can't quite figure out how to re-compile this script, is there a way I can just tell Tomcat to be aware of my /Users/RAVEN/bin/ directory in my $PATH variable?

Thank you!

Comment: Solution 2 is probably easiest; how is tomcat starting on that server? What kind of server is it? What is it running?

Comment: My server details are posted in the original post. As for how it is starting, I'm not sure but here is the contents of start_tomcat.sh which is whats executed at startup, `#!/bin/sh
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
export JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh`

Comment: Did you check Path in  .profile or .bash_profile? It should include your path something like this Path=~/Users/RAVEN/bin/hmmtop

Comment: Please attach tomcat error traceback so I can help you, also provide the type of your tomcat, is it apache tomcat or jakarta tomcat?

Comment: Its apache tomcat, here is the full error  http://www.wepaste.com/error/

Comment: Yes, my profile works. I can launch the program in my shell just by typing 'hmmtop'

Comment: You're talking about a Tomcat instance running on a server, so it's started when the server boots. Which user is it running as? If not as user "RAVEN", then it for sure it can't see *your* path.

Comment: ^ Good idea, didn't think of that. I checked, and it appears that it is running under RAVEN. What else could the issue be? `RAVEN    57   0.0  0.0  2435544    788   ??  Ss    7:54AM   0:00.02 /bin/bash /usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-launchd.sh`